# Huge Integer JavaScript Library

Tags: javascript, c++, math

Is there any JavaScript library that can be used for calculations involving 700+ Digits?
Also, how about the same thing in C++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### JavaScript:

- [Leemon Baird's BigInt library](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js). This seems to be popular. It's made specifically for cryptographic uses.
- My own [BigInteger library](http://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger). Similar to the Java BigInteger class, but all calculations are done in base-10.
- [jsbn](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/). Another BigInteger class similar to Java's. I've never used this one, but the API looks similar to mine.

#### C++:

- Most people use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).
- [CLN](http://www.ginac.de/CLN/) - Class Library for Numbers. I've used this in the past and it has a pretty nice API.

Answer (score 3):

For JS: How about [BigInt](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js)?

For C++: Google found me [this](http://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

Answer (score 1):

For C++ [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) has served me very well in the past for large numbers, it claims to be the fastest bignum library out there too, which is bound to be helpful for 700 digits.

Answer (score 0):

And then there is [MAPM (Arbitrary Precision Math Library)](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html) in C with C++ bindings. I incooperated it some years ago for testing. Was very simple thanks to C++ bindings.