# How to do bitwise AND in javascript on variables that are longer than 32 bit?

Tags: javascript, 64-bit, bit-manipulation

I have 2 numbers in javascript that I want to bit and. They both are 33bit long

in C#:

```
 ((4294967296 & 4294967296 )==0) is false
```

but in javascript:

```
 ((4294967296 & 4294967296 )==0) is true
```

4294967296 is ((long)1) << 32

As I understand it, it is due to the fact that javascript converts values to int32 when performing bit wise operations.

How do I work around this? 
Any suggestions on how to replace bit and with a set of other math operations so that bits are not lost?

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983206/632951

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split each of the vars into 2 32-bit values (like a high word and low word), then do a bitwise operation on both pairs.

The script below runs as a Windows .js script. You can replace WScript.Echo() with alert() for Web.

```
var a = 4294967296;
var b = 4294967296;

var w = 4294967296; // 2^32

var aHI = a / w;
var aLO = a % w;
var bHI = b / w;
var bLO = b % w;

WScript.Echo((aHI & bHI) * w + (aLO & bLO));
```

Comment: Could you give an example of splitting? Thanks!

Comment: Urgent notice - you must remember that Javascript not supports true 64bit values in a number, maximum 53bit. Because it uses float64 (double) to operate with any integer. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45425630/1848217

Comment: This still fails for values around -2^32 (but not -2^32 exactly). I couldn't find a solution for that. Rounding the `hi` part only works for few values. `hi` tends to stay at -1 when it should be -2 or something.

Comment: I made a quick test in javascript, it does not work on a=114287881752716 b=0x0fffffffff0000

Answer (score 15):

Here's a fun function for arbitrarily large integers:

```
function BitwiseAndLarge(val1, val2) {
    var shift = 0, result = 0;
    var mask = ~((~0) << 30); // Gives us a bit mask like 01111..1 (30 ones)
    var divisor = 1 << 30; // To work with the bit mask, we need to clear bits at a time
    while( (val1 != 0) && (val2 != 0) ) {
        var rs = (mask & val1) & (mask & val2);
        val1 = Math.floor(val1 / divisor); // val1 >>> 30
        val2 = Math.floor(val2 / divisor); // val2 >>> 30
        for(var i = shift++; i--;) {
            rs *= divisor; // rs << 30
        }
        result += rs;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Assuming that the system handles at least 30-bit bitwise operations properly.

Comment: Awesome! Do you have a function for bitwise or as well?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you would just change the single `&` to an `|`: `var rs = (mask & val1) & (mask & val2);` to `var rs = (mask & val1) | (mask & val2);`.

Comment: Awesome function but I couldn't get it to work with 32 bits or more.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't the function not working as advertised deserve a downvote? Which operations do not work (like the values of `val1` and `val2`, and the result of the function, along with the value you expect from the function)?

Comment: @palswim, amazing solution

Answer (score 1):

There are several BigInteger librairy in Javascript, but none of them offer bitwise operation you need at the moment. If you are motivated and really need that functionality you can modify one of those librairy and add a method to do so. They already offer a good code base to work with huge number.

You can find a list of the BigInteger librairy in Javascript in this question :

[Huge Integer JavaScript Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964139/huge-integer-javascript-library)

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest bit-wise AND, that works up to JavaScript's maximum number**

JavaScript's max integer value is 2^53 for internal reasons (it's a double float). If you need more there are good libraries for that big integer handling.

2^53 is 9,007,199,254,740,992, or about 9,000 trillion (~9 quadrillion).

```
// Works with values up to 2^53
function bitwiseAnd_53bit(value1, value2) {
    const maxInt32Bits = 4294967296; // 2^32

    const value1_highBits = value1 / maxInt32Bits;
    const value1_lowBits = value1 % maxInt32Bits;
    const value2_highBits = value2 / maxInt32Bits;
    const value2_lowBits = value2 % maxInt32Bits;
    return (value1_highBits & value2_highBits) * maxInt32Bits + (value1_lowBits & value2_lowBits)
}
```

Comment: It does not work on: bitwiseAnd_53bit(114287881752716, 0x0fffffffff0000)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem today and this is what I came up with:

```
function bitwiseAnd(firstNumber, secondNumber) {
    let // convert the numbers to binary strings
        firstBitArray = (firstNumber).toString(2),
        secondBitArray = (secondNumber).toString(2),
        resultedBitArray = [],
        // get the length of the largest number
        maxLength = Math.max(firstBitArray.length, secondBitArray.length);

        //add zero fill ahead in case the binary strings have different lengths
        //so we can have strings equal in length and compare bit by bit
        firstBitArray = firstBitArray.padStart(maxLength,'0');
        secondBitArray = secondBitArray.padStart(maxLength,'0');

        // bit by bit comparison
        for(let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
            resultedBitArray.push(parseInt(firstBitArray[i]) && secondBitArray[i]);
        }

        //concat  the result array back to a string and parse the binary string back to an integer
        return parseInt(resultedBitArray.join(''),2);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this problem.