# Javascript bitwise operator confusion

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to do some bitwise operations in Javascript,

```
0xff000000 | 0x00aabbcc
```

Which I expect to give me

```
0xffaabbcc     // == 4289379276;
```

However when running this, I get the result -5588020. I expect this has something to do with the fact that bitwise operations in javascript only operate on 32 bit numbers, but aren't the two numbers in question <= 32bit anyway? Can someone point out where I'm going wrong and how I can get the desired result?

I've tried the technique outlined at [How to do bitwise AND in javascript on variables that are longer than 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637702/how-to-do-bitwise-and-in-javascript-on-variables-that-are-longer-than-32-bit) with no luck.

---

Unable to post my own answer so putting it here for someone else to post...

Thanks for the comments, all. It turns out the answer at [Javascript bitwise operator confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936523/javascript-bitwise-operator-confusion) covers this. It turns out that JavaScript does bitwise operations on 32 bit SIGNED ints. My | oepration above was larger than the maximum possible range, therefore the result came back as a signed int. The solution is to shift the output right by 0, which apparently tells JS to treat it as unsigned again.

```
(0xff000000 | 0x00aabbcc)>>>0
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? That looks about right for signed integers.

Comment: I'm expecting the number 4289379276 as a result, but instead I get -5588020. What gives?

Comment: That is 0xffaabbcc as a signed integer.

Comment: Here is further discussion about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519708/javascript-bitwise-masking/28519794

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the right hex value, it's just not the integer value you're looking for.

4289379276 - 2^32 = -5588020

I suppose whether that suffices as is depends on what you're trying to do with your result.