# JavaScript Bitwise Masking

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation, tostring, parseint

This question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936523/javascript-bitwise-operator-confusion); however, I'd like to understand why this is working as it is.

The following code:

```
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0x000000ff', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0x0000ff00', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0x00ff0000', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0xff000000', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0x000000ff', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0x0000ffff', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0x00ffffff', 16)).toString(16));
console.log((parseInt('0xdeadbeef', 16) & parseInt('0xffffffff', 16)).toString(16));
```

Returns:

```
ef
be00
ad0000
-22000000
ef
beef
adbeef
-21524111
```

When what I am expecting from .string(16) would be:

```
ef
be00
ad0000
de000000
ef
beef
adbeef
deadbeef
```

What's going on with this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

---

With thank you to the responders and commenters below, and also to the following sources:

- http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html
- [JavaScript C Style Type Cast From Signed To Unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890994/javascript-c-style-type-cast-from-signed-to-unsigned)

Here is a solution that works by providing utility functions to convert a radix-16 32-bit number to and from a signed 32-bit integer:

```
// Convert 'x' to a signed 32-bit integer treating 'x' as a radix-16 number
// c.f. http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch11.html
function toInt32Radix16(x) {
    return (parseInt(x, 16) | 0);
}

// Convert a signed 32-bit integer 'x' to a radix-16 number
// c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890994/javascript-c-style-type-cast-from-signed-to-unsigned
function toRadix16int32(x) {
    return ((x >>> 0).toString(16));
}

console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0x000000ff')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0x0000ff00')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0x00ff0000')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0xff000000')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0x000000ff')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0x0000ffff')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0x00ffffff')));
console.log(toRadix16int32(toInt32Radix16('0xdeadbeef') & toInt32Radix16('0xffffffff')));
```

Which yields the expected output:

```
ef
be00
ad0000
de000000
ef
beef
adbeef
deadbeef
```

As well as some good learning on my part about JavaScript integer behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, all bitwise operations (and `&` among them) [return signed 32-bit integer as a result](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.10), in the range −2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive. That's why you have that extra bit (`0xde000000` is greater than `0x7ffffff`) representing a sign now, meaning that you get a negative value instead.

One possible fix:

```
var r = 0xdeadbeef & 0xff000000;
if (r < 0) {
  r += (1 << 30) * 4;
}
console.log( r.toString(16) ); // 'de000000'
```

Comment: Well, you don't really *loose* the bit, but it represents something different than you'd expect.

Comment: Thank you for your input (@Bergi too). It really helped and I have edited my question to include a workable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because bitwise operations (like `&`) are done on *signed* 32-bit integers in javascript. `0xFFFFFFFF`, where all bits are set, is actually `-1`, and the `0xde000000` you are expecting is actually `-570425344`.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It really helped and I have edited my question to include a workable solution.