# Does this func produce a 64 bit or signed 32 bit integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I collected funcs searching for conversion from integer to binary with different sizes, and re-visiting the code I'm thinking maybe what I recorded as 64 bit integer was actually signed 32 bit?

```
const readInt64 = (b) => {
  return parseInt(b.toString('hex'), 16)
}
const setInt64 = (int64) => {
  const b = Buffer.alloc(8);
  const MAX_UINT32 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
  const big = ~~(int64 / MAX_UINT32);
  const low = (int64 % MAX_UINT32) - big;
  b.writeUInt32BE(big, 0); // 00 00 01 53 00 00 00 00
  b.writeUInt32BE(low, 4); // 00 00 01 53 36 9a 06 58
  return b;
}
```

Which is it? I'm confused because if I understand right, Node.js doesn't support 64 bit integers. Or at least [not absolutely.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45425630/9400421)

Answer (score 2):

The max integer in Javascript is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `9,007,199,254,740,991` which is the largest mantissa value that fits in a double-precision floating point value which is how Javascript stores all numbers.

A double precision floating value is structured like this:

[image]

Which has 52 bits for the integer portion, one bit for the sign and 11 bits for the exponent.

Here's a simple test to illustrate:

```js
    let x = 0xffffffffffffffff;  
    console.log(x.toString(16))
```

and it will not output the exact 64 bit value that you tried to assign it (it will have been coerced into something that is not the same value).

---

Beyond the limit of the Number type, you would have to use `BigInt` which is limitless in what it can store, but takes more storage and is a lot slower for math operations and does not directly interoperate with the Number type.

Comment: @JLRishe - Corrected.  Copy/paste mistake.