# JavaScript bit-shifting

Tags: javascript, bit-shift

I would like to shift this unsigned number: 1479636484000 7 bits to the right. Is this possible in JavaScript?

Both

```
1479636484000 >> 7
```

and

```
1479636484000 >>> 7
```

returns an incorrect answer (for me). The correct answer should be 11559660031.
I guess there's some sign bit involved here, and maybe the number is too large to be supported. But is there any clever way of getting around it?

Comment: Yes, bitwise shifts are possible in JS, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators. Although I'm not sure whether there is a certain syntax to shift a x number of bits. I actually never usesd this functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do bitwise AND in javascript on variables that are longer than 32 bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637702/how-to-do-bitwise-and-in-javascript-on-variables-that-are-longer-than-32-bit)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as this is division and not and. The answer below is not applicable to bitwise and solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operations in JavaScript start by truncating the number to a 32-bit integer. Your numbers are too big. The "clever way" to get around that limitation is to implement your own numeric library.

Note that floating-point division by 128 gets you the right answer (if you drop the fraction).

Comment: ~~(n / 128) does not work. Math.trunc(n / 128) should work, but I don't have ECMA 6, so that doesn't help me. However, n / 128 - n / 128 % 1 does work! Thanks :)

Comment: You'll have exactly the same problem with the `~` operator as with the bit shift operators - they perform the same 32-bit truncation. `Math.floor()` will drop the fraction from a floating-point value however.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a string with the number and remove the last 7 characters and convert it back to a number.

```js
console.log((1479636484000).toString(2));
console.log((11559660031).toString(2));
console.log((1479636484000).toString(2).slice(0, -7));
console.log(parseInt((1479636484000).toString(2).slice(0, -7), 2));
```

Comment: Interesting, but I went for n / 128 - n / 128 % 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use BigInt to do bit-shifting of values greater than 32 signed bits.

```
let a = Number(BigInt(1479636484000) >> 7n);
let b = Number(BigInt(1479636484000) >>> 7n);
```

The reason for this is that JavaScript uses the [64-bit floating point number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), which has one sign bit, an 11-bit exponent, and 52-bit mantissa, which functions as 53 bits. JavaScirpt will truncate your number to a 32-bit signed integer.

Let's say you try the code `let e = 1 << 32`. This will result in the value 1, but `1 << 31` will result in `-2147483648`, or `0x80000000` (reminder: `0x8 = 0b1000`), which is the integer value next to the lowest possible 32-bit signed value (reminder: your computer stores integers in 2's complement). `1 << 30` results in `107374182`. This is terribly difficult to try to do bit shifting manually, so just use BigInt, even though it's going to be much slower.

I wish it was easier to work with 64-bit integers and bit shifting in JavaScript but you may have heard that JavaScript is a bad language, this is one of many reasons why.