# How to set 50th bit of javascript number efficiently

Tags: javascript, performance, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I need to set 50th bit of a number. But bitwise operators work in javascript only on lower 32 bits. So I my solution is:

```
function set50thBitOf(x) {
  hi=Math.trunc(x/2**32);
  lo=x%2**32;
  res=(hi|2**(50-32-1))*2**32+lo;
  return res;
}
```

Is there better way?

Comment: are you sure that you get the wanted result with a bitwise OR?

Comment: @NinaScholz ,yes it works, but I'm afraid about performance, because of division and multiplication used for spiting 64bit number to two 32bit parts and back

Comment: I can't think of another way to do it. Most other Q&A's on this topic suggest the same thing. Generally speaking, mathematical operations are very fast in modern JS engines, so I wouldn't worry about performance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637702/how-to-do-bitwise-and-in-javascript-on-variables-that-are-longer-than-32-bit  You could look into a BigInt JS library (there are several) which work with the numbers as strings, but then I would worry about performance.

Comment: You can try `x += (x % 2**50 < 2**49) * 2**49` or `x += (x % 2**50 < 2**49) ? 2**49 : 0` though no guarantees that it's better. Or `x += ((x / 2**32) & 2**17) ? 0 : 2**49`?