# Wrong result for left bit shift in JS

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have a script where I perform some operations on bits.  It is actually an attempt to display the operations performed in round 3, in the MD4 hashare algorithm. But I don't think this is very important.

The problem is that, in some cases, operations like XOR or shifting bits to the left, generate me signed(negative) results.

For example, I had the initial version of code . Here, in interaction 9 I get F as a binary number, but with sign in front, which apparently is not correct and possible.

```js
let A = 0x44496174;
console.log(`A = ${A.toString(2)}, ${A}`);
let B = 0x65737461;
console.log(`B = ${B.toString(2)}, ${B}`);
let C = 0x72655243;
console.log(`C = ${C.toString(2)}, ${C}`);
let D = 0x32303234;
console.log(`D = ${D.toString(2)}, ${D}`);

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {

  var AA = A;
  var BB = B;
  var CC = C;
  var DD = D;
  var F;
  if (i % 4 === 0) {
    F = B ^ C ^ D ;
  } else if (i % 4 === 1) {
    F = A ^ B ^ C;
  } else if (i % 4 === 2) {
    F = D ^ A ^ B;
  } else {
    F = C ^ D ^ A;
  }

  var P = (A + F) >>> 0; 

  var P2 = (P + i) >>> 0; 

  var result;
   if (i % 4 === 0) {
   result = ((P2 << 3) >>> 0)
  } else if (i % 4 === 1) {
     result = ((P2 << 7) >>> 0)
  } else if (i % 4 === 2) {
     result = ((P2 << 11) >>> 0);
  } else {
     result = ((P2 << 19) >>> 0)
  }
  
  A = DD;
  D = CC;
  C = BB;
  B = result;

  console.log(`Iteration ${i + 1}:`);
  console.log(`F = ${F.toString(2)}, ${F}`); 
  console.log(`P = ${P.toString(2)}, ${P}`); 
  console.log(`P2 = ${P2.toString(2)}, ${P2}`);
  console.log(`Result = ${result.toString(2)}, ${result}`);
  console.log(`A = D binar = ${A.toString(2)}, A decimal ${A}`);
  console.log(`B = A(F) binar = ${B.toString(2)}, B decimal ${B}`);
  console.log(`C = B binar = ${C.toString(2)}, C decimal ${C}`);
  console.log(`D = C binar = ${D.toString(2)}, D decimal ${D}`);
  console.log("*************************************************");
}
```

```
Iteration 9:
F = -1101100100010011001110110000000, -1820958080
P = 10010001101111001110110100100000, 2445077792
P2 = 10010001101111001110110100101000, 2445077800
Result = 10001101111001110110100101000000, 2380753216
A = D binar = 1110111010110100101001010000000, A decimal 2002408064
B = A(F) binar = 10001101111001110110100101000000, B decimal 2380753216
C = B binar = 11000001001110000000000000000000, C decimal 3241672704
D = C binar = 100101000101000011000000000000, D decimal 622080000
```

According to the algorithm, at iteration 9 F is calculated according to the formula `F = B ^ C ^ D`, A, B,C, D are taken from the previous iteration*

So we have

```
A = 11111110010001101000101010100000
B = 11000001001110000000000000000000
C = 100101000101000011000000000000
D = 1110111010110100101001010000000
```

According to the windows calculator, `11000001001110000000000000000000 XOR 100101000101000011000000000000 XOR 1110111010110100101001010000000 = 10010011011101100110001010000000`, but my code gives me `-1101100100010011001110110000000 (-1820958080 in decimal)`
Reading on the internet, I saw that it is recommended to move the bits to the right. without sign, i.e. `> > > 0`, modifying the code like this

```
if (i % 4 === 0) {
    F = (B ^ C ^ D) >>> 0 ;
  } else if (i % 4 === 1) {
    F = (A ^ B ^ C) >>> 0; 
  } else if (i % 4 === 2) {
    F = (D ^ A ^ B) >>> 0;
  } else {
    F = (C ^ D ^ A) >>> 0;
  }
```

Apparently, it worked, but now I have another problem. The last calculation in the algorithm, involves a bit shift to the left, with 3, 7, 11 or 19. Well, here in some cases also negative results appear (with sign - in front), but already `> > > 0` no longer works.
For example, iteration 3 implies an 11 bit left shift of the variable P2. So we have
`P2 <<< 11 = 10010101111111011000110101100111 < < < 11 = 01001010111111101100011010110011100000000000`
according to the windows calculator, instead the result in the script is `11101100011010110011100000000000`, which is not the result I expected
How could I fix this, so that the calculations are done correctly ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do bitwise AND in javascript on variables that are longer than 32 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637702/how-to-do-bitwise-and-in-javascript-on-variables-that-are-longer-than-32-bit)

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm not sure. I don't know what I should change in my code exactly

Comment: Getting negative results is by itself irrelevant, bits are bits, putting `>>> 0` after everything is unnecessary (it doesn't change the bits, only helps you view them the way you expect them to be). Note that `<<<` in the context of MD4 is intended to mean bitwise *rotation*, what you did on windows calculator does not reflect that (it can be configured to rotate as well, and make sure to set the size to dword)

Comment: @RaymondChen I don't think that helps at all, just gives OP a nice red herring. MD4 does not require bitwise AND (or any other operation) on values that have more than 32 bits.

Comment: @harold It was more about the general statement that JavaScript bitwise operations are performed as 32-bit signed integers. It looks like they generated a 43-bit value for `P2 << 11`, so I was drawing their attention to the 32-bit truncation (and the fact that bit 31 is a sign bit). I didn't realize that the underlying `<<<` operation was incorrectly interpreted.